# order of growth for loop worst case running time

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble with this. The inner loop depends on the outer loop and from trying out values of n, the loop runs 1+2+4...+sqrt(n) times. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int sum = 0;
for (int k = 1; k*k <= n; k = k*2)
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        sum++;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No image of code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `K` is the largest power of 2 with `K*K <= n`, then your sum is `1+2+4+8+...+K = 2K+1`.

`K` is clearly less than or equal to `sqrt(n)`, but it's also greater than `sqrt(n)/4` (because if not, then `2K*2K` would be less than or equal to `n`, contradicting the fact that `K` is the largest power of `2` with `K*K <= n`.

So `sqrt(n)/4 < K <= sqrt(n)`, and your runtime (`2K+1`) is between `sqrt(n)/2+1` and `2sqrt(n)+1`, and thus the complexity is Θ(`sqrt(n)`).